# Falsh Builder 4 - Switching Debug Mode - To Flash Perspective

Tags: flash, flash-builder, flashbuilder4

How do I swtich back to Flash Debug Perspective from Flash Perspective when I am debugging in Flash Builder 4? Earlier I got prompted with a dialog box whether to remember the setting.. but I can't seem to find the setting so far.

At the moment it's going into this view:

[image]

But I want to debug from the Flash Debug Perspective:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found it?[image]

it was hiding..

Comment: Yes! Play with those settings, there is also a setting on the "Run/Debug" preference (the parent of what your screen shot shows) that you can uncheck so that it doesn't switch perspectives when hitting a break point. Another thing you can do is let it switch perspectives and just customize the debug perspective to your liking :)

Comment: Cool - Thank you sir.. FB is not the best UI to navigate when compared to VS to change things..

Answer (score 1):

Perspective may be selected from the toolbar in the upper-right of Flash Builder:

[image: perspective]

Or, via the *Window* » *Open Perspective* drop down menu:

[image: window-perspective]

Comment: Hi Jason, I want to be able to debug from Flash perspetive. Even when I select Falsh perspective it keeps going to Flash Debug Perspective. Please see the screen shots above.

Comment: @Andrew there is a setting in preferences to make it stop doing that. The first time it asks you, and then it remembers that by default.

Comment: @Sunil D, can you please tell me where it is? I have been trying to find that setting..